# Instantiate loaded swf with arguments at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, class, actionscript, instantiation, loader

I'm working on a project that features a Master swf that loads in child swfs as required. Is there a way to load in these child swfs in such a way that the constructor in their document class can be called with arguments?

as an example:

I have a child class that is loaded in at runtime that can be given an alignment argument in its constructor.

I load that in at runtime as a class, and instantiate it with arguments in the parent, Master swf.

Obviously I could create a secondary 'constructor' in the child that builds what I want after instantiation, I'd just like to know if there is a way to manage instantiation of loaded swfs, and/or load them into classes rather than display objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loaded SWF is already a constructed object. With AS3 you can get the classname and instantiate a new object:

pass in the object you want to 'duplicate' in the function below. It will get the classname and convert it into a class. Then, it wil create a new instance of that class, where you can pass in some arguments

```
public function getClassObj(obj:*, constructorArgument:*):* {
    var objClass:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(obj)));
    var tempObj:* = new objClass(constructorArgument);
    return tempObj;
}
```

Comment: I thought that might be the only way, problem with that is the overhead with instantiating the original object only to throw it away once I've got a handle to its class.

Also, the constructor on the child would need to be built with default values in the constructor so that it could be instantiated without arguments.

Thanks for the reply. I think you're right; this is the only way. I'll stick with a secondary constructor method for now.